# Angular Login Issue with Authentication Service

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I have this error in my angular code when I try to run the code every single time:

```
✖ Failed to compile.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-12-13T08:51:03.123Z - Hash: a5d6a7dbdbf23ddb - Time: 156ms

./src/app/interceptor/auth.interceptor.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Angular/Gym/src/app/interceptor/auth.interceptor.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Angular/Gym/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:60:26

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:38:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './interceptor/auth.interceptor' or its corresponding type declarations.

38 import {AuthInterceptor} from "./interceptor/auth.interceptor";
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:12:11 - error TS2564: Property 'token' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

12   private token: string;
             ~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:13:11 - error TS2564: Property 'loggedInUsername' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

13   private loggedInUsername: string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:27:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

27     this.token = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:28:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

28     this.loggedInUsername = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:55:28 - error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

55   public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
                              ~~~~~~~




✖ Failed to compile.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names   | Raw Size
main.js             | main    | 65.20 kB | 
runtime.js          | runtime |  6.84 kB | 

3 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-12-13T08:57:45.773Z - Hash: 2bf15950175090e2 - Time: 249ms

Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:12:11 - error TS2564: Property 'token' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

12   private token: string;
             ~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:13:11 - error TS2564: Property 'loggedInUsername' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

13   private loggedInUsername: string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:27:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

27     this.token = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:28:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

28     this.loggedInUsername = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:55:28 - error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

55   public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
                              ~~~~~~~




✖ Failed to compile.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names   | Raw Size
main.js             | main    | 65.20 kB | 
runtime.js          | runtime |  6.84 kB | 

3 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-12-13T09:03:11.506Z - Hash: 47de080ef5615c75 - Time: 142ms

Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:12:11 - error TS2564: Property 'token' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

12   private token: string;
             ~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:13:11 - error TS2564: Property 'loggedInUsername' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

13   private loggedInUsername: string;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:27:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

27     this.token = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:28:5 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

28     this.loggedInUsername = null;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:55:28 - error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

55   public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
                              ~~~~~~~




✖ Failed to compile.
^C
```

this is my authentication service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/model';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthenticationService {
  public host = environment.apiUrl;
  private token: string;
  private loggedInUsername: string;
  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public login(user: User): Observable<HttpResponse<User>> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.host}/user/login`, user, { observe: 'response' });
  }

  public register(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.host}/user/register`, user);
  }

  public logOut(): void {
    this.token = null;
    this.loggedInUsername = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('users');
  }

  public saveToken(token: string): void {
    this.token = token;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  public addUserToLocalCache(user: User): void {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUserFromLocalCache(): User {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '');
  }

  public loadToken(): void {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return this.token;
  }

  public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    this.loadToken();
    if (this.token != null && this.token !== ''){
      if (this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub != null || '') {
        if (!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token)) {
          this.loggedInUsername = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub;
          return true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.logOut();
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

I don't know what is the wrong I checked the code a lot and searched a lot to fix it but nothing work the problem is with those two(this.token = null;
this.loggedInUsername = null;)I thought it was with the constructor but nothing wrong with the constructor

Comment: if u try to set null type must be "private token: string|null = null;" or "private token?: string;" . Here "?:" means undefined and some other types after ":". TypeScript rules in your tsconfig. Read them

Comment: I think you have set you tsconfig.json to compileroption.strict true. Do as @НикитаСереда if you want to maintain that level of strictness.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/model';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthenticationService {
  public host = environment.apiUrl;
  private token: string|null = null;
  private loggedInUsername: string|null = null;
  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public login(user: User): Observable<HttpResponse<User>> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.host}/user/login`, user, { observe: 'response' });
  }

  public register(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.host}/user/register`, user);
  }

  public logOut(): void {
    this.token = null;
    this.loggedInUsername = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('users');
  }

  public saveToken(token: string): void {
    this.token = token;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  public addUserToLocalCache(user: User): void {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUserFromLocalCache(): User {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '');
  }

  public loadToken(): void {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
  }

  public getToken(): string|null {
    return this.token;
  }

  public isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
    this.loadToken();
    if (this.token != null && this.token !== ''){
      if (this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub != null || '') {
        if (!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token)) {
          this.loggedInUsername = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token).sub;
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.logOut();
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: it gives me error with this (  public getToken(): string {
    return this.token;
  })

Comment: Error: src/app/service/authentication.service.ts:52:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

52     return this.token;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @MohamadJAlanbaki update answer